# How to make a generic method from below two method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two methods

```
    public List<Employee> saveEmployeeData(List<Employee> employee){

     //inserting data into db
     // returning the List<Employee>
    }
```

Second

```
    public Employee saveEmployeeById(Employee employee){

     //inserting or updating single employee based on id
    // returning the Employee object
    }
```

My code and logic is working as expected but to optimise the code I want to make one generic method and pass a list of Employee or one single employee based on some condition.
anyone can help here please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all the logic in the list one, I'd keep two method signatures though.

Also best to return Optionals from repo's to prevent null pointers in calling code.

```
public List<Employee> saveEmployeeData(final List<Employee> employee){
      //All logic
      // Return list of employees saved
} 


public Optional<Employee> saveEmployeeData(final Employee employee){
     return saveEmployeeData(Collection.singletonList(employee)).stream().findFirst()
}
```

Then you can just call `saveEmployeeData()` with either list or single employee as arg

Comment: Thanks. How can I have one generic method and passed a list or a single employee object and return according while calling that generic method

Comment: That's what this does, you can't write a single method that does both...

Comment: Okay got it. If I put all logic both for list of employee and only employee, how I will call repo's method from list one as I need to call twice, once for list of employee and another one for only employee

Comment: You just call saveEmployeeData() and pass either list or single employee, java will work out which method it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, which in my Opinion don't look elegant:

```
public static <T> T save(T emp) {
    if(emp instanceof List){
        //your code for list 
    }
    else if(emp instanceof Employee){
        // your code for Employee object
    }
    return emp;
}
```

and call this method like:

```
List<Employee> list; //populate your list
Employee e = new Employee();
save(e);
save(list);
```

Comment: I thought of this, but you'd have to check the list was of type Employee or you could just pass garbage in, making it more complex than just having two method signatures.

Comment: @123 I don't think it's so elegant either. To be honest, I find two overloaded methods with the same name the best.